# 500 Layout default not found. (Joomla 4)

Tags: php, component, joomla-4.x, extensions

I am trying to make a music component for Joomla 4

On the backend, my other forms work fine and the data is stored correctly in the database ( celebrity , album , etc...)

In the music form, when I click on the save and exit button, I get an error 500 Layout default not found. but the information is saved well in the database.

The codes used to display the forms are almost similar to each other and all the forms work correctly in the backend, but the music form has an error.

The code used in `com_myext/admin/views/music/view.html.php` file for music

```
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted Access');

use Joomla\CMS\Factory;
use Joomla\CMS\Language\Text;
use Joomla\CMS\MVC\View\HtmlView;
use Joomla\CMS\Toolbar\ToolbarHelper;
use Joomla\CMS\Helper\ContentHelper;

class AvisamusicdbViewMusic extends HtmlView
{
    protected $item;
    protected $form;

    public function display($tpl = null)
    {
        $this->item = $this->get('Item');
        $this->form = $this->get('Form');

        if (count($errors = $this->get('Errors'))) {
            throw new \Exception(implode('<br>', $errors), 500);
        }

        $this->addToolbar();

        return parent::display($tpl);
    }

    protected function addToolbar()
    {
        $input = Factory::getApplication()->input;
        $input->set('hidemainmenu', true);

        $user = Factory::getUser();
        $userId = $user->id;
        $isNew = $this->item->id == 0;
        $canDo = ContentHelper::getActions('com_avisamusicdb', 'component');

        ToolbarHelper::title(sprintf('%s: %s', Text::_('COM_AVISAMUSICDB'), Text::_('COM_AVISAMUSICDB_TITLE_MUSICS_EDIT')), '');

        if ($canDo->get('core.edit')) {
            ToolbarHelper::apply('music.apply', 'JTOOLBAR_APPLY');
            ToolbarHelper::save('music.save', 'JTOOLBAR_SAVE');
            ToolbarHelper::save2new('music.save2new');
            ToolbarHelper::save2copy('music.save2copy');
        }

        ToolbarHelper::cancel('music.cancel', 'JTOOLBAR_CLOSE');
    }
}
```

The code used in `com_myext/admin/views/musics/view.html.php` file for musics

```
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted Access');

use Joomla\CMS\Factory;
use Joomla\CMS\Helper\ContentHelper;
use Joomla\CMS\Language\Text;
use Joomla\CMS\MVC\View\HtmlView;
use Joomla\CMS\Toolbar\Toolbar;
use Joomla\CMS\Toolbar\ToolbarHelper;

class AvisamusicdbViewMusics extends HtmlView
{
    protected $items;
    protected $state;
    protected $pagination;
    protected $model;
    public $filterForm, $activeFilters;
public function display($tpl = null)
    {
        $this->items            = $this->get('Items');
        $this->state            = $this->get('State');
        $this->pagination       = $this->get('Pagination');
        $this->model            = $this->getModel('musics');
        $this->filterForm       = $this->get('FilterForm');
        $this->activeFilters    = $this->get('ActiveFilters');


        if (count($errors = $this->get('Errors'))) {
            throw new \Exception(implode('<br>', $errors), 500);
        }

        AvisamusicdbHelper::addSubmenu('musics');
        $this->sidebar = JHtmlSidebar::render();

        $this->addToolbar();
        return parent::display($tpl);
    }
protected function addToolbar()
    {
        $state  = $this->get('State');
        $canDo  = ContentHelper::getActions('com_avisamusicdb', 'component');
        $user   = Factory::getUser();
        $bar    = Toolbar::getInstance('toolbar');

        if ($canDo->get('core.create')) {
            ToolbarHelper::addNew('music.add');
        }

        if ($canDo->get('core.edit')) {
            ToolbarHelper::editList('music.edit');
        }

        if ($canDo->get('core.edit.state')) {
            ToolbarHelper::publish('musics.publish', 'JTOOLBAR_PUBLISH', true);
            ToolbarHelper::unpublish('musics.unpublish', 'JTOOLBAR_UNPUBLISH', true);
            ToolbarHelper::archiveList('musics.archive');
            ToolbarHelper::checkin('musics.checkin');
        }
if ($state->get('filter.published') == -2 && $canDo->get('core.delete')) {
            ToolbarHelper::deleteList('', 'musics.delete', 'JTOOLBAR_EMPTY_TRASH');
        } elseif ($canDo->get('core.edit.state')) {
            ToolbarHelper::trash('musics.trash');
        }

        if ($canDo->get('core.admin')) {
            ToolbarHelper::preferences('com_avisamusicdb');
        }

        JHtmlSidebar::setAction('index.php?option=com_avisamusicdb&view=musics');
        ToolbarHelper::title(sprintf('%s: %s', Text::_('COM_AVISAMUSICDB'), Text::_('COM_AVISAMUSICDB_TITLE_MUSICS')), '');
    }
}
```

The structure of my folders and files is as follows
i upload celebrity & celebrities for example for better understanding ( celebrities code , something like musics code )

[image]

admin\views\music\tmpl\edit.php code

```
<form action="<?php echo Route::_('index.php?option=com_avisamusicdb&view=music&layout=edit&id=' . (int) $this->item->id); ?>" name="adminForm" id="adminForm" method="post" class="form-validate">
    <?php if (JVERSION < 4 && !empty($this->sidebar)) { ?>
        <div id="j-sidebar-container" class="<?php echo $colClass; ?>2">
            <?php echo $this->sidebar; ?>
        </div>
        <div id="j-main-container" class="<?php echo $colClass; ?>10">
        <?php } else { ?>
            <div id="j-main-container"></div>
        <?php } ?>
        <div class="form-horizontal">
            <div class="<?php echo $rowClass; ?>">
                <div class="<?php echo $colClass; ?>12">
                    <?php echo HTMLHelper::_("$tab.startTabSet", 'myTab', array('active' => 'basic_configuration')); ?>
                    <?php echo HTMLHelper::_("$tab.addTab", 'myTab', 'basic_configuration', Text::_('COM_AVISAMUSICDB_FIELDSET_BASIC_INFO')); ?>
                    <?php echo $this->form->renderFieldset('basic_configuration'); ?>
                    <?php echo HTMLHelper::_("$tab.endTab"); ?>

                    <?php echo HTMLHelper::_("$tab.addTab", 'myTab', 'music_links', Text::_('COM_AVISAMUSICDB_FIELDSET_MUSIC_LINKS')); ?>
                    <?php echo $this->form->renderFieldset('music_links'); ?>
                    <?php echo HTMLHelper::_("$tab.endTab"); ?>

                    <?php echo HTMLHelper::_("$tab.addTab", 'myTab', 'music_trailers', Text::_('COM_AVISAMUSICDB_FIELDSET_MUSIC_TRAILER_URLS')); ?>
                    <?php echo $this->form->renderFieldset('music_trailers'); ?>
                    <?php echo HTMLHelper::_("$tab.endTab"); ?>

                    <?php echo HTMLHelper::_("$tab.endTabSet"); ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <input type="hidden" name="task" value="music.edit" />
        <?php echo HTMLHelper::_('form.token'); ?>
        </div>
</form>
```

Comment: This problem often occurs when the folder or files names are not spelled correctly. I am referring in particular to the upper and lower case of the words.

Comment: Can you turn of Debug On and Error messages to Maximum and the output should provide you more details about where the error is coming from and the stack trace of of calls that got you to the error.

Comment: @Irata my error on maximum and no any error...

Comment: @Gratia-Mira  i upload pic from my files here you can all my folder correct all with lower case i never use file and folder name on upper case for my component

Comment: When you press Save & Close the processing is going to your controller /music and the data is being saved so things are working to that point from what you have written. From your controller you are then trying to do some form of redirect back to the list view in /music . What do you have in your controller/music.php where you are handling the return to the List view?

Comment: @Irata i cant add more and more code in my question... just tell me how i can show you controller/music and controller/musics or...

Comment: In response to an earlier suggestions you said you have Error reporting On but you didn't mention whether Debug is On. With Debug on it should give you the file name and possibly line number of where the error is occurring which should narrow down where you need to be looking. If you have other Lists and Forms working and Music is a copy of one of those working, then carefully compare the /Music controller with the working one where you have made changes. Look at the code that is running after the Save has happened particularly where you call the List view. It seems like a typo is the issue.

Comment: @Irata my controller is copy like other all work as well and my debuging on maximum

Comment: Do you have the edit.php file inside your music/tmpl file?

Comment: @TerryCarter yes i added edit.php on my question

Comment: The Debug setting under the System tab only has a Yes or No, that is the one I am referring to. Error Reporting has various graduations like Maximum, Development, System etc. You should have Debug Yes and Error Reporting Maximum.

Comment: If Music is just a copy of something that works then @Gratia-Mira is probably close in that you may have a made a typo with an upper or lowercase character in one of the changes you had to make.

Comment: @Irata

i can upload my file on ftp and give u access to see it...

Comment: @TerryCarter i can upload my file on ftp and give u access to see it...

Comment: @Irata in joomla 4 error reporting have / system default , none , simple , maximum

Comment: That setting, Error Reporting, is under the Server tab of the Global Configuration. Under the System tab, to the left of the Server Tab, the first option is Debug that if you set to Yes you might see more information about your issue.

Comment: @Irata full error report https://freeimage.host/i/H1nowb9

Comment: @AliZangeneh if you want to throw the zipped file on a share somewhere I can take a look.

Comment: @TerryCarter http://dl1.avisapro.ir/com_avisamusicdb_1.zip

Comment: @AliZangeneh I will have to test on Joomla 3 through one of my other sites but it appears to work great in Joomla 4 on my end.

Comment: @TerryCarter irata ask me add this code 
   `$this->view_list = 'musics';`
after i added this code my component start work good.
if u remove this... not work, i ask this : in all my file i have not some code like this but all other part work as well why for music dont work ? i understand my problem is solve with this code but i try find my mistake ( why all my code work just with this code `parent::__construct();` but my music need add this line too  `$this->view_list = 'musics';`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your Save & Exit is supposed to bring you back to a list of records, views/musics, then the stack trace is showing you are trying to load a views/music, the singular or edit form view. Thus it is finding view/music/tmpl/edit.php and not views/musics/tmpl/default.php. Somewhere in your code you have a reference to music and not musics.

In your com_myext/admin/controllers/music.php you probably have reference to set the List view that is to be displayed once the music form is closed.

This is a sample that comes from a Joomla extension generator.

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->view_list = 'musics';
    parent::__construct();
}
```

However if you change the `musics` to `music` then it will produce the same error message you seeing.

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->view_list = 'music';
    parent::__construct();
}
```

`$this-view_list` is expecting a List view and you are providing an edit/form view.

Comment: i added this `$this->view_list = 'musics';` to my com_myext/admin/controllers/music.php

and after i use save and close i dont receive error
but i have 1 question ( In all my code i have not any code about view_list )
in all my controller i have this code `public function __construct($config = array()){parent::__construct($config);}` all my component part work !!! why just music dont work  ?

Comment: That is just one approach to setting the value for the list view. In your code somewhere is another approach that is setting a value of 'music' instead of 'musics'. You could compare a working example like celebrity with your music and look for somewhere you have used 'celebrities'(plural) in one and 'music'(singular) in the one not working. I would start with your controllers/music.php. If you still can't find it then do as @TerryCarter suggests and put a copy of your code somewhere it can viewed by people to help you or paste up the contents controllers/musics.php

Comment: tonight i try check all my code. if i dont find it, i share all my code and put link here, after joomla 4, i see many people beg other developer update music collection , or music download or try find some good music component for joomla 4, so i desicion make some free music component and after finish it give to all people want it as free. so then i upload it in git and other people can help for update it free for all...